# Differences between making a new file using the 'touch' command and hard-linking to a file

Tags: linux

What are the differences between when we make a new file using touch command and when we make a new hard-link to a file? Please explain it in detail.

Comment: `man ln` and `man touch`. These commands are not related in any way.

Answer (score 3):

[`touch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29) (with only a name as the argument) simply creates a new (empty) file. That file has no relation to any other file, it's stand-alone.

Creating a new [hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) (using [`ln`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29) without the `-s` switch) will create a second directory entry for the same "file". This means that you now have two directory entries (each representing a name) that access the same content: if you append to one of them, then that change is represented in the other. Deleting one, will keep the other one alive (because deleting a "file" per default only deletes the directory entry. Only if that was the last one, will the "real" content be deleted).

Answer (score 2):

'touch' creates a new file, while a hard link is just another name for the same file.

Try it with the following commands:

```
touch file1.txt
touch file2.txt
touch file3.txt
ln file3.txt file4.txt
echo "Hello world!" >> file1.txt
echo "Hello world!" >> file2.txt
echo "Hello world!" >> file3.txt
echo "Hello world!" >> file4.txt
```

Check the contents: file1.txt and file2.txt should both contain one line. file3.txt and file4.txt both contain two lines.

Answer (score 0):

`touch` will create a brand new file while
`ln` will link to an EXISTING file

Answer (score 0):

`man ln` and `man touch`. These commands are not related in any way.

Links don't allocate a new inode, other entries do. You can find out the inode number for files using

```
 ls -i
```

(or `ls -li` etc).

To find a file with a given inode number:

```
 find -inum 98398
```

**Inodes are unique only withing a filesystem** Hardlinking is only possible within a single filesystem